# How to find number of fields in shapefile using Python?

Tags: python, arcgis-desktop, arcpy, shapefile

I've been looking at the ArcGIS resources for python but I can't seem to figure this one out.
I'm looking for a method to gain access to the number of fields that are within a shapefile / feature class.  Is this information available via Python?

Answer (score 10):

Use [`arcpy.Describe`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Table_properties/000v00000033000000/).

```
fieldcount = len(arcpy.Describe(featureClass).fields)
```